# Remove Geofence Using Reset Button

Tags: android, android-geofence

How can i remove the Geofence? everytime i click the reset button it shows the following error-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

Here is my code-

```
public class GeofenceStore implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status>, LocationListener {
    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * Google API client object.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Geofencing PendingIntent
     */
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    /**
     * List of geofences to monitor.
     */
    private ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofences;

    /**
     * Geofence request.
     */
    private GeofencingRequest mGeofencingRequest;

    /**
     * Location Request object.
     */
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public GeofenceStore(Context context, ArrayList<Geofence> geofences) {
        mContext = context;
        mGeofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>(geofences);
        mPendingIntent = null;

        // Build a new GoogleApiClient, specify that we want to use LocationServices
        // by adding the API to the client, specify the connection callbacks are in
        // this class as well as the OnConnectionFailed method.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        Log.i("APi is :", "+" + mGoogleApiClient);



        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        // We want a location update every 10 seconds.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        // We want the location to be as accurate as possible.
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // We're connected, now we need to create a GeofencingRequest with
        // the geofences we have stored.
        mGeofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder().addGeofences(
                mGeofences).build();

        mPendingIntent = createRequestPendingIntent();

        // This is for debugging only and does not affect
        // geofencing.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            GeofenceStore.this.requestPermissions(new  String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        // Submitting the request to monitor geofences.
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.GeofencingApi
                .addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, mGeofencingRequest,
                        mPendingIntent);

        // Set the result callbacks listener to this class.
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(this);
    }

    private void requestPermissions(String[] strings, int i) {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 100: {
                {
                    Log.i("thanks","asdm");

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void removeGeofence(){

        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                // This is the same pending intent that was used in addGeofences(). 
                mPendingIntent
        ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult(). 

    }


    private void requestPermissions(int requestCode,String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Thanks for the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // permission was granted, yay! do the
                    // calendar task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You did not allow to access your current location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            // other 'switch' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    /**
     * This creates a PendingIntent that is to be fired when geofence transitions
     * take place. In this instance, we are using an IntentService to handle the
     * transitions.
     *
     * @return A PendingIntent that will handle geofence transitions.
     */
    private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
        if (mPendingIntent == null) {
            Log.v("HERE", "Creating PendingIntent");
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeofenceIntentService.class);
            Log.i("another class called",""+intent);
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            try {
                mPendingIntent.send();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return mPendingIntent;
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("THE CONNECTION HAS", "failed.");
    }


    public void onSuccess(AsyncTask.Status status) {

    }


    public void onFailure(Status status) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Status result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.v("THE RESULT IS", "Success!");
        } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
            // TODO Handle resolution
        } else if (result.isCanceled()) {
            Log.v("THE RESULT IS", "Canceled");
        } else if (result.isInterrupted()) {
            Log.v("THE RESULT IS", "Interrupted");
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

and here is the function to call from my maps activity, i have used a reset button to reset the geofence added.Pendind intent can be found in the above mentioned code. i want to know what is the problem with it?
The button is-

```
public void Reset(View view){


        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Coordinates");
         //delete all rows in a table
        request=request-1;
        GeofenceStore mgeofencestore=new GeofenceStore(this,mGeofences);
        mgeofencestore.removeGeofence();

        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"The Data was reset,Please click on 'Add Geofence' to add more Geofence",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new GoogleAPIClient every time create a new GeofenceStore object.  Since you call `removeGeofences()` immediately after, the GoogleAPIClient never has a chance to connect, and throws the error you are seeing.  Either place a copy of the GeofenceStore object you initially make in the calling class, or create a [static instance method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm) to get the current object and avoid recreating it.